# Redux state change but the component don't re render whene I back to the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, global-state

I have two screens, A and B. both of them uses the same global state

```
<Text style={Styles.textScoreHeader}>{this.props.profleInfos.Points}</Text>
```

using this :

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    folder: state.account.folder,
    theme: state.account.theme,
    whichAccount: state.account.whichAccount,
    profleInfos: state.account.profleInfos,
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ScreenA);
```

for screen A
and :

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    folder: state.account.folder,
    theme: state.account.theme,
    whichAccount: state.account.whichAccount,
    profleInfos: state.account.profleInfos,
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ScreenB);
```

for screen B.

In screen A I click a button to go to screen B where I change the `profleInfos.Points` global state like this:

```js
_Transaction(folder, apiName, code) {
  Transaction(folder, apiName, code).then(data => {
    if (data.success) {
      var theProfleInfos = this.props.profleInfos 
      theProfleInfos.Points = data.LoyPoints //changing profleInfos.Points
      const actionProfileInfos = { type: "SET_PROFILE_INFOS", value: theProfleInfos }
      this.props.dispatch(actionProfileInfos) // dispatch the action
    }
    this.setState({ scanningResponse: data, isLoading: false })
  })
};
```

I use `this.props.dispatch(actionProfileInfos)` instead of `mapdispatchtoprops` (tell me if I have to do it, but I prefer this method).
In this screen (B) I display the `this.props.profleInfos.Points` and it works fine (the value changes after scanning) but when I go back to the screen A (back button) the `this.props.profleInfos.Points` doesn't refresh.

PS. I have the same value in the drawer, if I open drawer I can see the change in the same value, maybe because I 'open' the drawer

Comment: Is `profleInfos` perhaps called `profileInfos` in somewhere else?

Comment: no @windowsill I call it profleInfos. the probleme is in screen A I can show the value but when I change it in screen B and go back to screen A it does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with `useFocusEffect` in screen A : this link helped me [see the class component part](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/#using-with-class-component)

This is my code:

```
   import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Reloader({ api }) {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      api();
    }, [])
  );
  return null;
}

// ...

class ScreenA extends React.Component {
  // ...

  _getProfileInfo(folder, apiName, LoyPhone, LoyRef, LoyCardNum) {
    getPeintreInfo(folder, apiName, LoyPhone, LoyRef, LoyCardNum).then(data => {
      const actionProfileInfos = { type: "SET_PROFILE_INFOS", value: data }
      this.props.dispatch(actionProfileInfos)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>
        <Reloader
          api={() => this._getProfileInfo(this.props.folder, 'GetProfileInfos.php', 'empty', 1, 'empty') />
            {/* rest of ScreenA component */ }
        </>
      );
    }
  }
```